# How to select first item of a list in <h:selectOneMenu> and render the page during initial load for the first selected item

Tags: jsf, render, selectonemenu

I have following code:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{AssetSummaryPageModel.selectedSensorId}"                                  styleClass="facility_dropDown_list" required="true" >

<f:selectItems value="#{AssetSummaryPageModel.childFacilitySelectionList}" required="true" />
<a4j:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@this" status="nameStatus"
                                    render="assetSummaryMainPanel"/>                                            
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

When I select one item from the dropdown, it is rendering the page for the selected item. But, I want to render the page (with the first item of the dropdown list) during initial load. How can I do that. Any help please!!!!

Answer (score 1):

That's easy. in your `AssetSummaryPageModel`-Bean you will add a new method with the `@PostConstruct` annotation so it will be called after the bean has been constructed. In this method you will set `selectedSensorId` to the first item of your `childFacilitySelectionList`.

When your page is being rendered, JSF will see that a value was already selected and will set this one as the selected one.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    selectedSensorId = childFacilitySelectionList.get(0);
}
```

Comment: I tried with this. But it is not rendering the page during initial page load. But when I select one item then it is rendering. 

Not getting the exact problem.

Comment: @Novis it is not rendering the page? how can it not render the page during the initial load? What do you mean?

Comment: I meant that when I will come to this page from other page, at that time I need to display corresponding information for the first item of the list. But it is not displaying anything when I come from other page to this page. When I come to this page and select one item from the dropdown list then the corresponding information of that item is being displayed. Clear?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer of the question. I decleared the following code in init() method in Pagemodel-Bean and it is being loaded during its initial load:

```
selectedSensor = getAsset().getCompanyModuleAssets().get(0);
                selectedSensorId = selectedSensor.getCoModAssetId();
```

Thanks :-)